# Gulp eslint doesn't find my .eslintrc file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, eslint

It looks like my `.eslintrc` file is not found my `gulp-eslint`

I defined a `lint` task:

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
  gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.jsx'])
  .pipe(eslint())
  .pipe(eslint.format());
})
```

It runs but doesn't show any error.

My `.eslintrc` file is defined in `src` folder. I tried to move it to the root folder of my project but it didn't change anything.

It's a pretty simple file:

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "classes": true,
    "jsx": true
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ],

  "extends": "eslint-config-airbnb"
}
```

When I run `eslint src` in the terminal, I get a bunch of eslint errors, which is fine.

Any idea what is not properly working?

Comment: You have to catch errors in gulp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint#usage) you need to fail on error in the pipe.

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
    // ESLint ignores files with "node_modules" paths.
    // So, it's best to have gulp ignore the directory as well.
    // Also, Be sure to return the stream from the task;
    // Otherwise, the task may end before the stream has finished.
    return gulp.src(['**/*.js','!node_modules/**'])
        // eslint() attaches the lint output to the "eslint" property
        // of the file object so it can be used by other modules.
        .pipe(eslint())
        // eslint.format() outputs the lint results to the console.
        // Alternatively use eslint.formatEach() (see Docs).
        .pipe(eslint.format())
        // To have the process exit with an error code (1) on
        // lint error, return the stream and pipe to failAfterError last.
        .pipe(eslint.failAfterError());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads-up, the [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring.html#configuration-file-formats) is extremely useful and succinct on using configuration files, their precedence of usage and how they are located. You can also add the path to specify the location of your configuration file for a particular pipe:

```
gulp.task('lint', function () {
  gulp.src(['src/**/*.js', 'src/**/*.jsx'])
  .pipe(eslint({ configFile: '.eslintrc'}))
  .pipe(eslint.format())
  .pipe(eslint.failAfterError())
})
```

In the gulp-eslint [documentation](https://github.com/adametry/gulp-eslint#eslintfailonerror) it should be noted that usage of the failOnError() and failAfterError() methods are advisable in that the task/stream is stopped and hence there is no invalid code written to the output.

If you use neither then the error is still caught but displayed only in the console output. So dependent on your task flow and design the destination file may still be written but you can conveniently correct the error immediately and carry on without having to start up your pipe processing/watch task again. An alternative is to look into [gulp-plumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber) or some other means whereby you're not breaking out of a gulp watch task and yet also not writing a file containing code that doesn't pass linting validation.